# Is there an easy way to construct a pandas DataFrame from an Iterable of dataclass or attrs objects?

Tags: python, pandas, python-attrs

One can do that with `dataclass`es like so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    i: int
    s: str


df = pd.DataFrame([MyDataClass("a", 1), MyDataClass("b", 2)])
```

that makes the `DataFrame` `df` with columns `i` and `s` as one would expect.

Is there an easy way to do that with an `attrs` class?

I can do it by iterating over the the object's properties and constructing an object of a type like `dict[str, list]` (`{"i": [1, 2], "s": ["a", "b"]}` in this case) and constructing the DataFrame from that but it would be nice to have support for `attrs` objects directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the dictionary at the heart of a dataclass like so

```py
a = MyDataClass("a", 1)
a.__dict__
```

this outputs:

```py
{'i': 'a', 's': 1}
```

Knowing this, if you have an iterable `arr` of type `MyDataClass`, you can access the `__dict__` attribute and construct a dataframe

```py
arr = [MyDataClass("a", 1), MyDataClass("b", 2)]
df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in arr])
```

df outputs:

```
   i  s
0  a  1
1  b  2
```

The limitation with this approach that if the `slots` option is used, then this will not work.

Alternatively, it is possible to convert the data from a dataclass to a tuple or dictionary using `dataclasses.astuple` and `dataclasses.asdict` respectively.

The data frame can be also constructed using either of the following:

```py
# using astuple
df = pd.DataFrame(
  [dataclasses.astuple(x) for x in arr], 
  columns=[f.name for f in dataclasses.fields(MyDataClass)]
)

# using asdict
df = pd.DataFrame([dataclasses.asdict(x) for x in arr])
```

Comment: This can have unintended effects if the class has any methods, right?

Comment: Or if it uses `slots` instead of dict

Comment: you're right, its probably better to use `astuple` instead.

Comment: the initial solution does not have any unintended effects if the class has methods, however it does break when slots are used.

Comment: Good solution. I forgot about the `asdict` method. Most importantly, it works for the `attrs` library. I will edit your solution accordingly and accept the answer.